# C# properties: why does this work?

Tags: c#, properties, set, readonly

maybe there's something i missed in the latest version of C# but to me this code should not work yet it does..

```
public class FileManip {
    public FileManip(string path) {
        appPath = path;
    }

    private string appPath {
        get;
    }
    //...............
}
```

Comment: What is there to say, yes, it does work, as you have seen for yourself.  What makes it work, C# was defined in such a way that this is valid.  They get to do that with their language.

Comment: One having the get makes it `readonly`. Those properties can be `set` in the constructor.

Comment: "maybe there's something i missed in the latest version of C#" -- "Getter-only" properties was implemented in c# 6 according to [the wiki](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6): "Auto-properties can now be declared without a setter".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When a property has a `get` with an implementation, you have a property that does not allow writing:

```
public class FileManip {
    public FileManip(string path) {
        AppPath = path;   // <<===== ERROR
    }
    private string AppPath {
        get { return @"c:\temp\"; }
    }
}
```

However, when you have a `{ get; }` with no implementation, it's a so-called read-only property. It has been added in C# 6. You can write to it only from the constructor. All other parts of your code access this property as read-only.

Comment: ahh i see.. i knew that regular variables marked as readonly could be set in the constructor (making it different than a Const) but have never seen this with properties before. thx

Answer (score 1):

Readonly properties can be set from the constructor, which you are doing.

Comment: You can set them as many times as you want from the constructor, not just once.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to change it as

```
private const string appPath = "something";
```

Comment: did just that since there was no more need to use a property